# Check if target joint position is valid

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic, rospy, movegroup, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I was wondering if there is a way to check if a goal pose of a planned path (planned in moveit with OMPL) is a valid pose, meaning that joint position constraints, collision, etc. are taken into consideration.
A Python function like

> bool check_if_pose_if_valid(joint_position)

would be great.

Thanks for your answers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302951/check-if-target-joint-position-is-valid/) by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2018-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way should be to use the StateValidationService of the `move_group` node, by calling the service `/check_state_validity` with [this message](http://docs.ros.org/api/moveit_msgs/html/srv/GetStateValidity.html). You will need the RobotState, which you can get from the `/get_planning_scene` service with [this message](http://docs.ros.org/api/moveit_msgs/html/srv/GetPlanningScene.html).

In the [definition of the StateValidationService](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/melodic-devel/moveit_ros/move_group/src/default_capabilities/state_validation_service_capability.cpp), you also find a pretty good example of how to do the checks yourself, in case you want to avoid calling the service too often.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2018-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on 2018-09-11**:
Thanks a lot for you answer. I will try to test the ''/check_state_validity'' service and mark this question as answered if it works for me.